# Blank space below the status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, statusbar, uiwindow, cgrect

In app delegate I use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` (which is by default) to set frame for the window.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

But when I try to launch the app, I see blank space between my view and the status bar.
[image]

If I set the frame this way

```
CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -20.0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];
```

It'll be ok, but it won't detect taps at the bottom 20 points of the screen.

What's wrong here? Please help.

P.S. I don't use IB, don't set frame for any view except window (because it doesn't help).

Comment: How is your autoresizing mask set?

Comment: For the window? I didn't set it.

Comment: Autoresizing mask for the root view controller. You should probably `NSLog` all the dimensions first so that you could see if the problem is in window bounds or controller bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by setting the property `wantsFullScreenLayout` of the root view controller to `YES`.

P.S. It's not my first app where I write `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` from scratch, but I never had this problem...